# pseudo-class and pseudo-element not working inside of nested style on postcss

Tags: css, pseudo-class, postcss

I've tried to use `:last-child` pseudoclass inside of nested style it won't working on postcss

Of course I've added `postcss` and `postcss-nested` to my project

```css
/* without nesting it works */
.container {
  outline: 2px dashed red;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}

.container .child {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin-right: 1rem;
  color: red;
}

.container .child::after {
  content: '*';
}

.container .child:not(:last-child) {
  color: blue;
}

/*
But with nesting it won't work

.container {
  outline: 2px dashed red;
  height: 500px;
  width: 1000px;
  display: flex;
  & > .child {
    font-size: 2rem;
    color: red;
    &::after {
      content: '*';
    }
    &:not(:last-child) {
      color: blue;
    }
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="child">first</div>
  <div class="child">second</div>
  <div class="child">third</div>
  <div class="child">last-child</div>
</div>
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/yondonjamts_g/pen/YzQOjVN?editors=1100)

Answer (score 0):

Removing the & symbol should do the trick. & means element has both classes.

An improvement to the readability of your code would be to only change the last-child rather than not the last-child element, eg set the .child to be blue and last-child to be red;